PySpark: New column with uppercase name is dropped unexpectedly
I am trying to add a new column CHANNEL_ID in my PySpark DataFrame based on conditional logic using pyspark.sql.functions.when and after that, removing the old column channel_id, which is no longer needed. However, the new column doesn't appear in the resulting DataFrame when I use the uppercase name CHANNEL_ID. It seems to drop the new CHANNEL_ID column instead.
Here is my code:
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 101),
        (2, 102),
        (3, 103)
    ], schema="id int, channel_id int"
)

df.show()

This shows the expected DataFrame:
+---+----------+
| id|channel_id|
+---+----------+
|  1|       101|
|  2|       102|
|  3|       103|
+---+----------+

I then try to add a new column CHANNEL_ID and drop the original channel_id column:
df.withColumns(
    {
        "CHANNEL_ID": f.when(f.col("channel_id") == 101, "First channel")
        .when(f.col("channel_id") == 102, "Second channel")
        .otherwise("-")
    }
).drop("channel_id").show()

I expected the output to show the id column and the newly created CHANNEL_ID column, but instead, this is the result:
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
+---+

Question:
Why is the CHANNEL_ID column being dropped, even though I am trying to drop channel_id? It seems like the uppercase name CHANNEL_ID is somehow interfering with the drop method. If I rename the column to something else (like channel_alias), it works fine.
Is this behavior related to case sensitivity or naming conflicts in PySpark? Any clarification or suggestions to resolve this would be appreciated!

According to the spark official documentation: Both regular identifiers and delimited identifiers are case-insensitive.
When using withColumns, CHANNEL_ID will replace channel_id. The solution is to use different column names.
